# spring-saml assertion from fake idp

Tags: spring-saml

SP metadata generated with WantAssertionsSigned="false" allow to process fakes saml response in spring-saml sp.

Maybe this is obvious, but i'd like experts to confirm it.

If i create a fake idp with "non signed metadata" and 
in relying-party.xml i set signAssertions="never" encryptAssertions="never",

i can send to the sp any assertion i want because  verifyAssertionSignature is skipped and the check
"// Make sure that at least one assertion contains authentication
// statement and subject with bearer confirmation "
is always positive.

I have changed default and
boolean wantSigned = true;
in   org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl
because i cant allow it in no way.

thanks in advance

alessandro

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `wantAssertionsSigned` to `false` does mean that the incoming messages do not require digital signature (equivalent of the never/never in Shibboleth). I agree that it's a dangerous setting and will make its meaning more explicit.